# How to view Infinispan statistics in WildFly?

Tags: statistics, wildfly, infinispan

I have enabled statistics for my cache container in `standalone.xml` as follows:

```xml
<cache-container name="..." marshaller="JBOSS" modules="org.infinispan.hibernate-cache" statistics-enabled="true">
    <local-cache name="entity">
        <heap-memory size="100"/>
        <expiration max-idle="300000" lifespan="300000"/>
    </local-cache>
    <local-cache name="local-query">
        <heap-memory size="10000"/>
        <expiration max-idle="100000"/>
    </local-cache>
    <local-cache name="timestamps">
        <expiration interval="0"/>
    </local-cache>
</cache-container>
```

Where can I go to view the statistics? I am using WildFly 26.

Comment: I think statistics are supposed to be accessible via JMX (for instance by starting 'jconsole'). See https://docs.jboss.org/infinispan/9.1/apidocs/jmxComponents.html#Statistics

Comment: To enable JMX, add: `<jmx enabled="true" domain="jboss.datagrid-infinispan"/>` as child of `<cache-container>`